# Insert mpdf TOC with page number for dynamic data PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf, tableofcontents

I am using mpdf to create PDF files from data extracted from a database. There are three sections in pdf which i need to display in TOC with their page number on which they are appearing. They can appear on separate page or on a single page as well when data is too short. Below is my code currently using:

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->SetFont('avenirnext');
    $mpdf->SetTitle($title);
    $mpdf->SetAuthor('Blavatnik');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet2, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet3, 1);
    $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
    $mpdf->SetHtmlHeader($header, 'OE');
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer, 'OE');
    $mpdf->AddPage('', // L - landscape, P - portrait 
            '', '', '', '', 20, // margin_left
            20, // margin right
            5, // margin top
            25, // margin bottom
            10, // margin header
            10); // margin footer
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output($title . '.pdf', 'd');
```

**I need to display TOC on first page and it also has some designing so I think it has to be done via html as displayed in example below:**

```
https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/table-of-contents.html
```